# Excel 2010 issue in Sharepoint 2013 - We are sorry we cant open your work book

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, excel-services

Can anyone help me with this issue?

I am getting an error while opening a excel file in the SP 2013 browser window:

**"We're sorry. we could not open your workbook. Its possible corrupt or using a file format that's not supported.  Do you want to try open the file in excel?"**

The excel sheet is macro-enabled with password protection. I have tried removing the protect view for the file. Is there any way to resolve or hide this error message at least through script.

Thanks in advance !!

-Dhana

Answer (score 0):

Workbooks that are protected (encrypted with password protection) cannot be viewed in a browser window.

In an on-premises environment where you're using Excel Services or Excel Web App, protected worksheets cannot be viewed in a browser window.

To remove protection, open the workbook in the Excel on the desktop.

Besides, save your file as .xlsx format and compare the results.

Differences between using a workbook in the browser and in Excel for your reference:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-using-a-workbook-in-the-browser-and-in-Excel-F0DC28ED-B85D-4E1D-BE6D-5878005DB3B6

Comment: Thanks Lisa. So you told we can open the excel file in native application. Is there any way to just to hide or disable the alert while launching the file.